# VBA for changing doc properties Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a code that need to change a custom document property in a word document. This custom document property is the information that must be inserted in the document but sometimes need to be changed as requested. So far I have created the code for inserting the custom document property, it works fine, see below.

```
Sub AddCustomDocProperty()

Selection.Fields.Add _
    Range:=Selection.Range, _
    Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    Text:="DOCPROPERTY  ""ProjectName"" ", _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
    
End Sub
```

The custom document property is named as ProjectName which will be linked with a specific field where the user will input the project name, e.g. New Screwdriver

Let's say the custom document property shows New Screwdriver and I need to change to New Screwdriver 2021.

How can I write a code that change the docproperty based on the new input given in Project name field?

I tried to find something in the forum but I did not find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code creates a DOCPROPERTY *field*, not the property itself. See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/MixedDocProps.htm.

Comment: Thanks Charles Kenyon I will read the article that you mentioned. I hope I can undestand that as I am new in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A user can't easily change the value of such a field by simply typing. Whatever additional text they type will fall outside the field. Then it's difficult for you to retrieve with VBA. Consider using a content control, formfield, or even a bookmarked table cell for their input instead.

But to answer your question, this will update a custom document property:

```
Sub SetProp()
    ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("ProjectName").value = "New Screwdriver 2021"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks John, but for some unknown reason it did not work for me. After running the macro wrote by you error 5 pops-up.

Comment: I don't know what error 5 is. What is the exact text that appears in the error message? Refer to Charles comment on your original post. Have you created the custom document property yet? If not, the VBA can't update it.

Comment: Run-time error '5 = Invalid procedure call or argument - the custom document property is already created quite strange but in anyway using the link mentioned by Charles it worked. John many thanks for your great support.